Angular PrimeNG TabMenu reload on same item
I want to know how to manually reload an active menu item of PrimeNG.
I know that there are ways to reload the current component manually but i want to know if there's any method implemented by PrimeNG to reload the active item?
Something like: [onSameActiveItem] = "reload"
There's an example:
<p-tabMenu
  [model]="items"
  [activeItem]="activeItem"
  (activeItemChange)="onActiveItemChange($event)"
/>
<div class="router-container">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>


You can configure that the same route navigation should not reuse using the below code.
export class SomeComponent {
  constructor(
    private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => { return false; };
  }

  onActiveItemChange(item: any) {
    this.router.navigate([item.path]);
  }
}

